# Fujitsu touchpad not working after linux installation

Tags: touchpad, fedora-24

I have windows 10 on my Fujitsu lifebook A514. Touchpad was working fine. But on other linux OS it's not working at all. I have tried Fedora 24 and Endless OS. Maybe there is some driver issue. 
I have tried the workaround mentioned [here](http://it.xceptn.com/?p=138) and got no luck.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like "synaptics pointing" package from your distro's repo. Then use your desktop environment's tools to configure it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I didn't found any setting like synaptics pointing... I am new to Linux

Comment: Can *you* elaborate more?
**If** you are on Fedora, does https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_enable_touchpad_click answer your question at all?

Comment: Yes, I am using Fedora 24.. And my touchpad isn't working at all, and the link you provided does not answer my question